# Meteor 1.4 version install packages Error

Tags: meteor, package

I am new here and Meteor. I have some package install problems.

When I did step of this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvkQNTIfbQk&index=3&list=PLLnpHn493BHFYZUSK62aVycgcAouqBt7V

I get an error like this

> C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0-1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\ddp\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:165
>
> ```
>  throw error;
>  ^
> ```
>
> Error: No metadata files found for isopack
>   at: /C/Users/Home/AppData/Local/.meteor/packages/stolinski_stylus-multi/1.4.3
>   at Isopack.*loadUnibuildsFromPath (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack.js:900:13)
>
>   at C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:520:19
>
>   at Array.forEach (native)
>
>   at Function.*.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0-1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
>   at C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:519:11
>   at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
>   at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>   at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
>   at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>   at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
>   at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>   at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
>   at Object.download (C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:454:20)
>   at C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:611:18
>   at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:572:21
>   at C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0-1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\ddp\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\fiber_pool.js:32:39

What can I do for instal this packages?

Answer (score 0):

I get same error. 
I use Windows 10. Problem is windows file path length limitation.
I solved the problem by following the steps below.

1. Uninstall the Meteor
2. Go to  C:/Users/(your user name)/AppData/Local/.meteor
3. Try to remove all. Probably get "Destination Path Too Long" error.
4. Skip this files and remove other folders and files.
5. Rename the names as (for example 'a') of the remaining folders and their contents. This can take time and be boring.
6. Delete .meteor folder
7. After that install Meteor again.
8. Create Meteor Project

> meteor create newApp
>
> cd newApp
>
> meteor npm install

9. Add required packages to .meteor/packages file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue today.

***Solution***

1. Go to location **C:\Users\a\AppData\Local.meteor\packages**
2. delete folder named **stolinski_stylus-multi**
3. restart meteor using command "**meteor**"

**NOTE** : It will automatically download that same package automatically and then it will build entire project and run successfully. I am not sure why it does that, but this is how I made it work.

Answer (score -3):

Er no. That won't work for Windows users. You will want to install meteor using the Windows installation tool located [here.](https://www.meteor.com/install) In that video you referenced, the command line installation only works for Linux/Mac.

Comment: I install for windows and fix . I have install first two packeges * kadira:flow-router and kadira:blaze-layout *                                                                                                        but when I try to instal other packes * erasaur:meteor-lodash
stolinski:stylus-multi
fortawesome:fontawesome
spiderable
fastclick
raix:handlebar-helpers
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:autoform
accounts-ui
accounts-password
matb33:bootstrap-glyphicons
msavin:jetsetter
zimme:active-route
gwendall:auth-client-callbacks  it is makes this error

Comment: He's not installing meteor, he's installing meteor packages through the command line. I'm getting a similar error when I do "meteor add gwendall:auth-client-callbacks